# Using Tumblr's new Photo Set plugin outside of Tumblr

Tags: jquery, gallery, photo, tumblr, image-gallery

As you can see examples here: [TUMBLR'S NEW PHOTOSET](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/photoset)  is an amazing photo gallery addition for Tumblr. But I'm developing a website with lots of photographs and I would like to use galleries in the same way.

So, is there anyway to use that plugin in my common webpages? Or is there any other plugin which does the same beautiful thing to photosets?

Especially in this blog, that addition is used brilliantly : [example2](http://fuel.istockphoto.com/)

Shortly, I want the same auto-calculated mosaic effect.

Thanks for your kind answers.

Comment: There are dozens of jQuery plugins that will give show a lightbox much like tumblr.  As for the mosaic effect, you'll either need to do a little searching or write that part yourself to fit in with your site's look and feel.

Comment: as lightbox effect, yes there are plenty of betters actually. But what I wanted to learn is that mosaic part. (I realized that this is the same thing as facebook album preview on walls too) It seems I should code it myself as you told. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin that replicates Tumblr's photosets and extends the functionality a little bit, you can check it out here: https://github.com/PixelUnion/Extended-Tumblr-Photoset

It's meant to be used on Tumblr (since it's really just an enhancement to include things like captions and EXIF data), but you should be able to use the JS that's available.

Comment: Thx for the respond but it seems like your project mostly mentions about the slide part too. What I wanted is a jquery approach to make the same effect that Tumblr does with a server side programming probably. (When I find some time, I'll write it and share with you) Thx for sharing your project again :)

Comment: Ahhh, I see. So not just the jQuery part of it but the whole backend as well. Good luck with the project!